# Android: can't read new line from database

Tags: android, database, newline

i've got a database with a field in var_char(2000).
in this field there's text with some new line, like a normal text written:

```
hello
i am davide
bye
```

i put this text in a textview but i see the text like a unique line (hello i am davide bye), without newlines.
in iphone it is all normal and i've done nothing particular... but here no.
how can i?
i've tried with replace \n or replace \r\n o other things but without success.
Also with Html.fromHtml()

---

the singleLine(false) is deprecated, and it doesn't work.
also text doesn't work. it see the newline as a space

Comment: try printing the charsequence byte by byte. Then you will know whether the sqlite is indeed returning a next line character

Comment: sorry but i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `android:singleLine="false"` to your textView.

Edit:
If this does not work check whether the string has a new line character using below code

```
char[] chararray= mString.toCharArray();

for(char temp:chararry){
   int value = temp;
   System.out.println(value);
}
```

Decimal value of Newline is either 10 or 13. While space character is 32.

Edit2 : I think TextView does not go to next line for \r which is 13. 
So do

```
 mString = mString.replaceAll("\r","\n");
```

Comment: i've tried and i see the 13 around the list of numbers. so now?

Answer (score 0):

did you try changing the datatype in sqlite?, your varchar to just text? if not, try doing so maybe it'll help

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the multi-line feature of the text view.

If you created the text view from an XML file, add this attribute to the text view :

```xml
<TextView
    [...]
    android:singleLine="false"
    [...] />
```

If you created the text view programmatically, try to use the following method instead :

```java
TextView myText = [...]
myText.setSingleLine ( false );
```